# CSS hack for width attribute on IE8 and below

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I am trying the following CSS hack for IE8 and below:

```
 .class {
        background-color: #BFBFBF;
        width: 1154px;
        width: 930px \9;
       }
```

But this CSS hack is affecting IE9 also.

Could you please help me to apply this width attribute only for IE8 and below?

Comment: Sorry I didnt try that @user125697

Comment: There's a possibility the developer has no access to the HTML, which is where a CSS hack comes into play. There's even the possibility the developer has no access to the selector, so a property hack only would be the only possibility.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are better answers - you should be using conditional comments. But to answer your question as to why what you're doing isn't working, try

```
width: 930px\9;
```

Without the space.

Comment: I had tried this earlier and now also but didnt work. I dont want to use other options as I am using SASS, so the code added to SASS files get converted to CSS files and cannot add conditional statement at SASS as it throws exception while compiling

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional comments.

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE 8<br />
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

While I would advise against browser-specific CSS at all, your best bet would be to use conditional comments.

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]><html class="ie8-"><![endif]-->

.ie8-.class {
    width: 930px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than resorting to a bunch of hacks, I would really advise taking advantage of javascript (see http://modernizr.com/) to place your browser type as a class in the html tag.  So, the markup of your page in IE8 would include:

```
<html class="ie8">....
```

That way, you can reference browser specific classes in your style sheet:

```
.class {
    background-color: #BFBFBF;
    width: 1154px;
}
.ie8 .class {width: 930px}
```